# jQuery scrollTo plugin jumping to top of page in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webkit

I searched for this but the answer I assumed would be the solution to my problem isn't working. This seems awfully trivial considering I've dealt with things much more complicated in the past, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong.

```
$('.link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.scrollTo('2000px', 300);
}
```

this code, in Chrome and Safari, jumps to the top of the page before scrolling 2000 pixels. I've been reading through other lists that they had other events that were the problem, but this is the ONLY javascript code (with the exception of jQuery and scrollTo includes) on the test page I'm working on.

Comment: well, this appears to be a problem with Chrome and Safari on my machine. I tried the exact same code on other computers, with fresh installs of both and they're working fine. Not sure where the problem actually lies. Going to uninstall and reinstall Google Chrome to see if that's a solution.

Comment: the problem was a rogue extension that I had installed in chrome. If anyone has a similar problem, try deactivating all extensions. ugh, a totally frustrating problem to have, but at least it was user (me) error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to duplicate this bug with jQuery 1.5.1 and jQuery.SCrollTo version 1.4.2 by enabling the "Screen Capture (by Google) - Version: 4.0.1" extension in Google Chrome 11.0.696.34 beta.

Simply disabling that extension and refreshing the page resulted in the bug going away under those same circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just the standard javascript `window.scrollTo(0,'2000px')` to see if it behaves the same way?

Answer (score 0):

1. I face this issue in chrome too.
2. Whenever the body element does not have a visible horizontal scroll bar and when you call jquery.scrollTo(someElement) the browser scrolls itself to the top
3. You can do one of the following

   - Make sure you have a scroll bar before you call scrollTo(). There are many ways to do it. Easiest would be to set overflow:scroll for the body element
   - Wait for the jquery to fix this problem in the animate() (which is called eventually by scrollTo) code by some means

In my application (no horizontal scrollbar), when I tried debugging the jQuery's animate code I found out that whenever scrollLeft is set to zero the vertical scrollbar in chrome moves to top.
Hope this helps.